# Display custom tags on pages that have a specific page parent

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, pages, query-posts

I would like to use Using the WP_Query or Query_Posts method.

I'm currently using the query_post method.

```
$terms_array = array();

if ($strurl == "somesite.com"){
 $resparent = "18219"; //Page ID
 $nocat = "-2,-4,-5,-6,-1014,-875,-25,-301"; //Omitted Pages ID
}

query_posts('post_type=page&posts_per_page=500&taxonomy=guidance&cat='.$nocat.'');
 if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'post_tag');

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
      if (strlen($term->slug) >1){
      $terms_array[] = $term->slug.",".$term->name ;
 }
    }
endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();
wp_reset_query();
endif;
```

This method does not seem to work.

So basically i would like my taxonomy Tags to be displayed only if they are tagged to a page that has a specific parent.

Comment: Never ever use `query_posts`. It breaks the main query object, and many plugins and custom code relies on that

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have a loop that displays up to 500 pages. If the page parent = 18219 than you want to query the tags for that page. As far as I know, by default WP does not allow you to tag Pages, only Posts. But let's pretend you have a plugin that allows you to do that... Inside your loop you can check to see if the page has a parent equal to the ID you're looking for.

```
    //Check if this page has a parent equal to $resparent
    if($post->post_parent == $resparent){

      $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'post_tag');

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
          if (strlen($term->slug) >1){
            $terms_array[] = $term->slug.",".$term->name ;
          }
        }
    }
```